# Android startForeground notification disappears

Tags: android, service, notifications

My android application starts a service to listen to headset buttons. While the service is running, I want to show a notification. Because it's also important it does not get killed, I decided to use the startForeground function in my service.

in the OnCreate of the service, I start BuildNotification():

```
 public void BuildNotification() {

    // Make sure the launch mode of the activity is singleTask, otherwise it will create a new one
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListItemsActivityScroll.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

     // Build notification
     note = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
             .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_text))
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vp_launcher)
             .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_content))
             .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();

     startForeground(1, note); 
  }
```

The first time the service is started, the notification gets displayed and stays in the status bar until the service is destroyed. However, if the service gets created for a second time, it shows only for a couple of seconds.

After it disappeared, the service is still running. I also executer 'adb shell dumpsys activity services', which does show the service to be running in the foreground and gives me also the correct flags set to the notitication:

```
isForeground=true foregroundId=1     foregroundNoti=Notification(contentView=com.example.mediabuttontest/0x10900a7 vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x62)
```

The 0x62 flags would mean the following are active: FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, FLAG_NO_CLEAR, FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

Which I think is correct for keeping the notification active.

Does anyone understand this behaviour? Why it does work the first time the service is created, but not the second time? Is there any error in my code?

**EDIT**: Thanks for your time and comments, I've created another test application and started removing code until the problem disappeared. In the end, it was caused by enabling / disabling a broadcast receiver component:

```
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(mRemoteControlResponder,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Somehow, this makes the notification disappear. In the document it also mentions about 'DONT_KILL_APP' can make your application behave unpredicatable:

*Be careful when you set this since changing component states can make the containing application's behavior unpredictable.*

I guess that's true :)

Comment: show your full code here..